# How to generate Decimal (9,2 ) from Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

Is there any way to generate a Decimal(9,2) from Hibernate ? Right now I do it manually in the MySql database myself. IN the hibernate class I just use double.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@Column` annotation like this:

```java
class Product {
    ...

    @Column(name="cost", precision=9, scale=2)
    private BigDecimal cost;

    ...
}
```

Check out https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Column.html for more information.

Comment: so BigDecimal should do it . ok

Comment: @Julia19 If it solved your problem, please accept it as an answer.